CodePen url query string to control zoom level of a pen
I'm looking for the answer in the CodePen's documentation without finding it, so I don't know if what I'm looking for is expected: is it possible to pass the zoom level (1, 0.5, 0.25) via url (like the link to a specific timestamp in YouTube with url#t=seconds), so that I can maybe open the link with the appropriate zoom level (useful via CSS's media queries or javascript, for different devices, or if you embed the pen in your webpage and check the device)?
Something like https://codepen.io/yitaverse/details/ZEgKEvp?z=0%2E5 or https://codepen.io/yitaverse/details/ZEgKEvp#z=0%2E5 (%2E = dot, in HTML URL Encoding Reference), if not https://codepen.io/yitaverse/details/ZEgKEvp?z=0.5 or https://codepen.io/yitaverse/details/ZEgKEvp#z=0.5, or something like it, for the url?
It would be better if the zoom automatically adapted to the device, but it seems that you have to set it manually, if you know how to do it (for those who are not familiar with CodePen and visit the page): it would be useful to have a setting in your profile (an autozoom), which could allow the pen to adapt automatically to the device, instead of manually (like autosave, which can be activated or not).
